# Почему появляется ошибка unexpected token

Tags: javascript, webpack, babel

Почему при выполнении этого кода

```
class NAME {
    checkErrorMethods = () => {
        console.log('test')
    }
}
```

выходит ошибка?

**client:159 ./src/js/scripts.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (8:9)**

P.S: Переношу сервисы с одного проекта на другой, и там такой функционал работает. В похожих вопросах пишут, что нужна среда es2015. Но в песочнице es2015-2016 выходит та же ошибка.

В первом проекте такой кусок кода

```
class NAME {
  checkErrorMethods = method => {
    const methods = {
      свойства
    };
    return methods[method];
  };
};
```

Этот код нигде не используется, сделан для демонстрации

Comment: Так это же разные совсем куски кода.

Comment: в 1 примере кода , что вы делаете, сделали незадекларируваную переменную тест, только зачем?Изучите классы https://learn.javascript.ru/es-class